# Automatically select right “From” address in Mail Mac OS X based on history

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

In Mail for iOS 8+, when you write a new message, the app will automatically select your "From" address based on the history of your conversations with this contact.

I would really like to use the same feature in Mail for Mac OS X. Does anybody knows a plugin or a script for that? I could not find anything alike the internet (maybe because the function is somewhat difficult to formulate...).

To be more schematic:

I have my email addresses X and Y installed on my iPhone or iPad. My default address is X, but I am used to write emails to contact C with my address Y.

I start a new message. By default, "from" address X is selected. I type the address of my contact C in the "To" field. And now the magic happens: As most of my previous conversations with C were made with my address Y, the app automatically changes my "From" address from X to Y.

Comment: Be sure to provide [feedback to Apple's OS X Mail.app team](http://www.apple.com/feedback/mail.html). Every report and request helps justify the required engineering time.

Comment: Thank you very much @GrahamMiln. I have contacted Apple support.